# why am i not getting the state

Tags: redux, react-redux

am a newbie in redux, am trying to add an item to the basket but am getting, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState'). why am i not able to get the state, please what am i not doing properly

hey is my code

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
}

export const basketSlice = createSlice({
    name: "basket",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addToBasket: (state, action) => {
            state.items = [...state.items, action.payload]
        },
    }
});

export const { addToBasket } = basketSlice.actions;
export const selectItems = (state) => state.basket.items;
export default basketSlice.reducer;


import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { selectItems } from "../slices/basketSlice"

const Header = () => {
 
    const items = useSelector(selectItems);

  return (
    <header >
       <div className="flex items-center flex-grow p-1 py-2 bg-slate-800">  
       </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: You are getting an error message about a `getState` call, but you are not showing any code where you call `getState`. That slice looks good, so that's not the problem. Can you share the code where you actually try to access state?

Comment: import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { selectItems } from "../slices/basketSlice"

const Header = () => {
 
    const items = useSelector(selectItems);

  return (
    <header >
       <div className="flex items-center flex-grow p-1 py-2 bg-slate-800">  
       </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header;

Comment: Is your app wrapped in a Provider that gets your `state` as a prop?